# Add formula with VBA to range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, formula

Dear Overflow community

I`d like to add a formula some cells (4, x), for each sheet (sh). I'm running the sub in a for-loop in the main code, which runs thru each column (a). I've tried many things but unfortunately my code just won't run:

```
Sub InsertFormula(ByVal sh As Worksheet, ByVal a As Long)

Formel = "=TEXT(" & a & "$1;'TTT')"
sh.Cells(4, a).Formula = Formel

End Sub
```

EDIT:

```
Sub InsertFormula(ByVal sh As Worksheet, ByVal a As Long)

Formel = "=TEXT(R1C" & a & ",""TTT"")"
sh.Cells(4, a).FormulaR1C1 = Formel

End Sub
```

Thanks very much, working perfectly

Comment: Why "won't run" ? What error message do you get ?

Comment: you defined `a`  as your column, but you are actualy sending it to your `Sub` here as `Long` (as a Number). in your `Formel = "=TEXT(" & a & "$1;'TTT')"` you actualy need it as a letter of your column, so you need to convert your column from number to a letter

Comment: how can i do that? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

In VBA you need commas to separate function arguments in formulas regardless of your local settings. (You can get around it by using `.FormulaLocal` but I don't recommend it since it might not run on other machines)

Furthermore, as Shai Rado noted, you use a number as a column name. In this case I would use `R1C1` format so you don't have to convert the number into a letter, i.e.

```
Formel = "=TEXT(R1C" & a & ",""TTT"")"
sh.Cells(4, a).FormulaR1C1 = Formel
```

Answer (score 1):

This takes the column letter as opposed to the column number. Also I've changed the formula to use `"` instead of `'` and corrected the `TEXT` formula as these two are part of the reason the formula was failing

```
Sub InsertFormula(ByVal sh As Worksheet, ByVal Col As String)
    Dim Formel As String

    Formel = "=TEXT(" & Col & "$1,""TTT"")"
    sh.Range(Col & "4").Formula = Formel

End Sub
Sub test()
    Call InsertFormula(ActiveSheet, "A")
End Sub
```

Comment: Was going to update this with `R1C1` notation as well as `A1` however @arcadeprecinct has already posted it. Choose which ever one you prefer

Answer (score 0):

Just try this to overcome your problem: put Formel directly without using keyword .formula

```
Sub InsertFormula(ByVal sh As Worksheet, ByVal a As Long)

Formel = "=TEXT(R1C" & a & ",""TTT"")"
sh.Cells(4, a) = Formel

End Sub
```